# Why are purple slugs appearing when I kill enemies?

Tags: dead-cells

On one of my Dead Cells runs, whenever I killed an enemy a small purple slug with mushrooms on its head would appear. It would follow me around for a few seconds before exploding.

Why are these purple slugs appearing? Do they do anything?

[image: purple slugs]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those creatures are called **Biters**.

[image]

One of your equipment should have something that reads "biters crawl from dead", they attack enemies for you, according to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/deadcells/comments/f99ocu/can_anyone_explain_what_these_purple_slugs_are/).